# Virtual methods with multiple argument types in C++

Tags: c++, virtual

Lets say I have a base class A that I want to have a method getName that can take in either an integer or a string as the argument. So I create:

```
virtual string getName(int index) = 0;
virtual string getName(string key) = 0;
```

Now, I want to create two different subclasses B and C. B only needs the `getName(int index)` and C only needs the `getName(string key)`.
However, if I dont overwrite both methods in both subclasses, I get an error. But if I do this, then B and C will have an empty methods because they dont need the other case of `getName`

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: When you will use your classes B and C, using your Base interface, how will you know whether it supports getName with int or string parameter?

Comment: @AlexandreTHOUVENIN I doubt it, the definition probably shouldn't be the same for both type `int` and `string`.

Comment: Could you please add an usage example of `A`? Why do you need both `getName` overloads in the same base class?

Comment: Instead of describing how you want to solve the "problem" you've created... describe what you want to do/support (without architectural decisions).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you actually want two different interfaces: one that supports `getName(int)` and one that supports `getName(string)`.

```
struct GetNameInt {
    virtual string getName(int index) = 0;
};

struct GetNameStr {
    virtual string getName(string key) = 0;
};

struct B : GetNameInt { /* ... */ };
struct C : GetNameStr { /* ... */ };
```

---

If you **really** need a single base class with the same interface, and you **only know at run-time** whether you'll need a `string` or an `int`, you might want to use `std::variant`:

```
struct GetName {
    virtual string getName(std::variant<int, string>) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using inheritance properly. I strongly recommend reading more about the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

You need to split the class A into two classes (interfaces) - Aa and Ab, where Aa would hold getName(int index) and would have getName(string key), like:

```
class A {
//does not define neither of the getName methods
}

class Aa {
    virtual string getName(int index) = 0;
}

class Ab {
    virtual string getName(string key) = 0;
}

class B : A, Aa {
    //inherits from A and defines string getName(int index)
}

class C : A, Ab {
    //inherits from A and defines string getName(string key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the best I can come up with to keep a common parent between B and C while still preserving some type safety and compile time check:

```
struct CommonA //protect this if possible
{
    template<class type>
    string getGenericName(type index);
    virtual ~CommonA() {}
};

template<class indexType>
struct A : CommonA
{
    virtual string getName(indexType index) = 0;
};

struct B : A<int>
{
    string getName(int index) override {cout << index << "\n"; }
};
struct C : A<string>
{
    string getName(string index) override {cout << index << "\n"; }
};

template<class type>
string CommonA::getGenericName(type index)
{
    cout << "generic call: \n"; 
    return dynamic_cast<A<type>*>(this)->getName(index);
}

int main()
{
  CommonA b = B();
  CommonA c = C();
  b.getGenericName(1);
  c.getGenericName(string("hello world"));
}
```

Note that this solution is not a standard OOP solution but a template solution.

Edit: my templated A<> class is the same as Vittorio Romeo's solution using template instead of name pasting (name pasting is evil)

Comment: Put virtual destructor in `CommonA`, use (and check) `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast` to have a better type safety.

Comment: @Jarod42 done, feel free to edit further if you spot other room of improvement

Comment: Looks overengineered to me. At least it smells bad to mix templates and inheritance in my opinion.

Comment: @zett42 actually not that much. The mixin pattern is based on templates and inheritance. The class commonA is indeed overengineering (to match with OP's code) but templating A is excellent practice.

Answer (score -2):

By simply don't making them pure virtual, but  just virtual:

```
struct Blub
{
    virtual void do1() {} // default definition
    virtual void do2() = 0; //has to be overridden
};
```

Comment: I think OP wants at least one of the two methods defined in the derived class